# Views not removing as expected

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

So this function is intended to remove a Unit object, and its corresponding view from a list of views. It then checks the rest of the Units, and if the previously removed one was a pre-requisite for another Unit, it recurses and removes that unit too, and so on.

The Units are removed correctly from storage, and displayed back in the pending display, but not all of the removed units' views are removed from "temp".

Edit: The function is working entirely when a maximum of one unit is in each semester, but leaves things behind otherwise.

Any insight you could offer into why this is occuring would be muchly appreciated.

```
    void removeLinkedUnits(Unit inUnit)
{
    int sem;
    for(sem = semesters.size() - 1; sem >= 0; sem--) //iterate through each semester containing units
    {
        int unit;
        for(unit = semesters.get(sem).getUnits().size() - 1; unit >= 0; unit--) //iterate through each unit in a semester
        {
            String[] pres = semesters.get(sem).getUnit(unit).getPrerequisites();
            int i;
            boolean toRemove = false;
            for(i = 0; i < pres.length; i++) //Compare list of pre-requisites against removed unit.
            {
                if(pres[i].contains(inUnit.getUnitID()))
                {
                    toRemove = true;
                }
            }
            if(semesters.get(sem).getUnits().get(unit).getCorequisites().contains(inUnit.getUnitID()))
            {
                toRemove = true;
            }
            if(toRemove) //Unit relies on previously removed unit
            {
                Unit unitx = semesters.get(sem).getUnit(unit);
                semesters.get(sem).remove(unitx);
                LinearLayout temp = vertUnitLayouts.get(sem);
                temp.removeViewAt(unit);
                scheduledUnits.remove(unitx.getUnitID());
                removeLinkedUnits(unitx);
                redrawPendingSpinners();
                pendingUnits.add(unitx);
                LinearLayout pendingLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pendingLinear);
                pendingLinear.addView(makePendingView(unitx));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to call the requestLayout() or invalidate() after you remove the unit object..

Comment: Neither appear to have had any effect.

Comment: Can you confirm me that you have called the requestLayout() or invalidate() of the parent view? And called one of those methods after the loop?

Comment: I put temp.invalidate()/temp.requestLayout() after temp.removeViewAt(unit).
Neither had any effect on the situation.

Comment: I guessed that you can't see the changes because of for loop. You can see the final change you made in the layout. Just test this without loop, then only you can spot out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.
temp (vertUnitsLayout) contained 2 items per Unit, not the 1 I was expecting. Misunderstood how my partner was constructing his views.
I need to use debugger more :S

Replaced:

```
    temp.removeViewAt(unit);
```

With:

```
    temp.removeViewAt(unit*2);
    temp.removeViewAt(unit*2);
```